# Code not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why can't my code update?

**CODE:**

```
    //Create a new Insurance
    Insurance oInsurance = new Insurance();
    oInsurance.Active = true;
    oInsurance.Address1 = txtAddress.Text;
    oInsurance.Address2 = txtAddress.Text;
    oInsurance.Name = txtName.Text;
    oInsurance.City = txtCity.Text;
    oInsurance.BillingProviderAddress = txtNameSubmit.Text;
```

Comment: I doubt anyone can start answering your question without at the very least knowing what the problem is, the error, the crash or ...

Comment: Update in the sense, where u r going to update.

Comment: please show definition of  oHCSInsurance.UpdateInsurance(oInsurance);

Comment: @NDC, its a dll from our client

Comment: any error message comes while updating?

Comment: Post you code on what is not getting updated? Are you using database? share you code pls..

Comment: thanks for deleting the original question with a thank you note.  That is very helpful to the community.

Comment: Please post original question code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update a record you have to pass a primary/unique key of the table. As you are passing other parameter, you have to pass key Column to update,

```
oInsurance.PrimaryKey/UniqueColumnName = Value;
```

Finally when the query will build, it will miss the *where* part,

```
update table set columnName=@Value where ID = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

When trying to update a record a unique value should be passed to update that specific record or a group of records (it may be sometimes primary key),

```
update tablename set columnName=@columnvalue where uniquerecordkey = @identifyingkeyvalue
```